# Terminal problems

Tags: 12.10, command-line

When I try to install something on my ubuntu I get erors on terminal saying package wasn't located.

```
latvietis@datorslatvietim:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for latvietis: 
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
latvietis@datorslatvietim:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from your error message, your source list is malformed. So it must to be "repaired".

One method to do this is to generate a new `sources.list` using this site: http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ and then to replace with your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file (you will need to have root privileges to do this).